# How to change the Bundle Display Name for SwiftUI in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to change the Name beneath my App icon for a SwiftUI app in Xcode 4.3

A quick Google search states that I need to change the Bundle Display Name - I can't find that.   Please assist.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is based on Xcode 14.3. Select the target and go to build setting than search product name. Give the name you want to give. it will reflect under the icon of app.

see the attached image below. [image]